# How to print/log reactjs rendered dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a component with ReactJS.

I would see the html react renders with my console, so for example:

```
 import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

 class CustomComponent extends React.Component {


   render() { return (<div>Custom</div>); }
 }
```

And instead of:

```
ReactDOM.render(<CustomComponent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I would do something like:

```
console.log(<CustomComponent />);
```

but when in my console I call:

```
babel-node myfile.js
```

I get:

[image]

How can I print/log the effective html tags that react renders?

thanks.
bye.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdomserver.rendertostring

Now you're just printing the virtual dom representation which need to be transformed to string.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use 
`string renderToStaticMarkup(ReactElement element)`

it will return you the StaticMarkup